# Integrating excel sheet with java swing

Tags: java, excel, swing

How can i get a cells value from an excel sheet using java swing ?
I progressed till opening the excel app using Desktop.getDesktop().open().
My aim is to get a value from an excel sheet and display the value in my java swing.
Is it possible using any libraries. 
Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: There are several and you should do some research, [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) is probably one of the better open source, but there are others, like JExcelAPI

Comment: Thankss.... feels intresting....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Apache POI. It can open Excel files and access individual cells: http://poi.apache.org/

Here's an example on how to use it:

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
//..
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\test.xls"));

//Get the workbook instance for XLS file 
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

//Get first sheet from the workbook
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

//Get iterator to all the rows in current sheet
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

//Get iterator to all cells of current row
Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
```

It is from this site: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/