# Display excel sheet in JFrame

Tags: java, excel, swing

Is there any way to display excel sheet in `JFrame`  directly rather than reading all cells? Just as we display Web page in frame directly like below, or do I have to read the excel file?

```
JEditorPane website = new JEditorPane("http://smo-gram.tumblr.com/");
```

Comment: Short answer is ... kind of, no, not really.  There are some commercial API's which will allow you to embed a native component into your API, but these are heavy weight and won't play well with Swing.  There are some other commercial APIs which will allow you to read an excel spreadsheet and have ready made "view" components, but you'd need to look into them to see if they meet your needs...

Answer (score 2):

You can display the Excel file in the default spreadsheet app of your OS by using the `Desktop` API. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Integrate With the Desktop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html).

Or you can access the data of the file by using API's found in: [Integrating excel sheet with java swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877885/integrating-excel-sheet-with-java-swing?rq=1)